# When I sort the date, some of the sorted data are randomly wrong using pandas. What might be the cause?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I obtained the information from Twitter and would like to sort the dates. However, some of the dates are incorrectly sorted, switching from date to month and vice versa.Is there something wrong with the code or the original data? My original data looked fine, though. Can anyone help?

**Raw data**

[image]

**my code**

```
df05 = pd.read_csv("01_clean_2020-07.csv")
df05['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df05['date'], dayfirst=True)
df05_count = df05['date'].dt.date.value_counts().sort_index().reset_index()
df05_count.columns = ['date','count']
```

**output**

```
date    count
0   2020-03-07  2 **wrong
1   2020-04-07  1 **wrong
2   2020-07-13  5
3   2020-07-15  1
4   2020-07-16  1
5   2020-07-20  1
6   2020-07-21  7
7   2020-07-22  3
8   2020-07-23  3
9   2020-07-24  3
10  2020-07-25  2
11  2020-07-26  1
12  2020-07-28  1
13  2020-07-29  1
14  2020-07-30  1
15  2020-07-31  2
16  2020-09-07  1 *** wrong
17  2020-11-07  6 *** wrong
18  2020-12-07  3 *** wrong
```

Comment: How can `7/16/2020` (your first entry) be day first? What's the 16th month? Never heard of it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here seems day is not first, but month, so remove `dayfirst=True`:

```
df05['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df05['date'])
```

Also is possible specify format:

```
df05['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df05['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

Comment: I'm still unfamiliar with the pandas.Thank you very much for your comment. It works.

Comment: @tassaneel - Yes, problem is if working input data

Comment: I have tried both but the last three rows are still wrong.

Comment: @tassaneel - seems there are mixed formats `MM/DD/YYYY` and `DD/MM/YYYY`. Pandas working here like - convert to months if possible (`MM/DD/YYYY`), if not, swap it ( `DD/MM/YYYY`)

Comment: @tassaneel - It means if `12/7/2020` - and use `df05['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df05['date'])` - then 12 is month. pandas cannot thinking like all another months are 7, so swap one month with day.

Comment: @tassaneel - `12/7/2020` and if use `df05['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df05['date'], dayfirst=True)` then 7 is month, but problem for all another dates with first number l;ess like 13 - `7/3/2020` - month is 3, because 7 is July. But if  `7/13/2020` - month cannot be 13, so pandas swapp it and 7 is July.